# How to return the function value along with the returned element from Enum.max_by in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How may we return the `function value` along with the `returned element` from `Enum.max_by/3` in Elixir

I have this case:

```
def fuzzy_match(x, items) do
    m = Enum.max_by(items, fn i -> TheFuzz.compare(:jaro_winkler, x.desc, i.desc) end)
    IO.puts("fuzzy: #{inspect(m)}")
    m
end
```

It is not enough to know the best matching item, I also need to know the matching thresh hold and to eliminate poor matches below 0.7

With `Enum.max_by/3` it is not possible to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.max_by/3` doesn't allow this. You could either call the function again on the returned value, or if that's not an option (if the function has side effects or is expensive to compute, for example), you can use `Enum.reduce` like this if the input is a list:

```
defmodule A do
  def max_by_with_value([h | t], f) do
    Enum.reduce(t, {h, f.(h)}, fn x, {max, max_value} ->
      value = f.(x)
      if value > max_value, do: {x, value}, else: {max, max_value}
    end)
  end
end

IO.inspect A.max_by_with_value([1, 4, 3], &(&1 * 2))
```

Output:

```
{4, 8}
```

Comment: Thanks, Enum.max_by_with_value would be valuable in the Enum lib

Comment: For simplicity my answer only works with lists, not all enumerables. An efficient implementation for all enumerables would be more complicated.

Comment: i'm even struggling to adapt your example to the format in the question i have

Comment: How about `{max_item, max_threshold} = A.max_by_with_value(items, fn i -> TheFuzz.compare(:jaro_winkler, x.desc, i.desc) end)`?

Comment: I went with you first advice, the cost was not that much, i just re-run the match with the returned item

Answer (score 1):

Since `Enum.max_by` is nevertheless greedy (there is no way to tell whether the maximum was found without inspecting all the elements,) I would go with way easier (and more readable) approach than the [perfectly working of course] @Dogbert’s one. Map everything first, do call a normal `Enum.max_by` then:

```rb
def fuzzy_match(x, items) do
  items
  |> Enum.map(& {&1, TheFuzz.compare(:jaro_winkler, x.desc, &1.desc)})
  |> Enum.max_by(fn {_, jw} -> jw end)
end
```